# Why does loading an xml file in vb.net require a document type definition in the current directory?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am writing a VB.NET Program in Visual Studio, and whenever I try to load an xml file I get an error about the document type definition not being found in the same directory as the file. I'm not planning on validating the file, but I need to take care of the error some how so that the application runs without any errors, I tried attaching the document type definition to my project, but that doesn't fix anything. Is there a way I can always load the same type definition? I guess I am just really confused about this error... Here is some screenshots of the error and the code that generated the error:

[image: Xml Error Screenshot]

```
 Public Sub ReadFile(file As String)
        gscale = 10
        gmargin = 50
        xmldoc = Nothing
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(file)
        Try
            xmldoc = XDocument.Load(file)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End Try
        Do While (reader.Read)
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
                    xmltag = reader.Name
                    If reader.HasAttributes Then 'If attributes exist
                        While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                            'Display attribute name and value.
                            attributenumber = attributenumber + 1
                            xmlattributetype(attributenumber) = reader.Name
                            xmlattributevalue(attributenumber) = reader.Value
                        End While
                    End If

                Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                    xmltagvalue = reader.Value
                Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.


            End Select
            totalnumberofattributes = reader.AttributeCount
            Interpret(xmltag, xmltagvalue, xmlattributetype, xmlattributevalue, reader.AttributeCount)
            attributenumber = 0
        Loop
        gscale = 0
        gmargin = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteFile(wfile As String)
        Dim emptystring As Boolean
        emptystring = String.IsNullOrEmpty(wfile)
        If emptystring = False Then xmldoc.Save(wfile)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Interpret(tagname As String, tagvalue As String, attributetype() As String, attributevalue() As String, numberofattributes As Integer)
        Dim x1 As Single
        Dim x2 As Single
        Dim y1 As Single
        Dim y2 As Single
        Dim thickness As Single
        Dim layer As Integer
        Dim parsesuccessful As Integer

        Select Case tagname
            Case "margin"
                parsesuccessful = Int32.TryParse(tagvalue, gmargin)
                If parsesuccessful = False Then gmargin = 50
            Case "scale"
                parsesuccessful = Int32.TryParse(tagvalue, gscale)
                If parsesuccessful = False Then gscale = 1
            Case "wire"
                For i As Integer = 1 To numberofattributes
                    If attributetype(i) = "x1" Then
                        x1 = attributevalue(i)
                    ElseIf attributetype(i) = "x2" Then
                        x2 = attributevalue(i)
                    ElseIf attributetype(i) = "y1" Then
                        y1 = attributevalue(i)
                    ElseIf attributetype(i) = "y2" Then
                        y2 = attributevalue(i)
                    ElseIf attributetype(i) = "width" Then
                        thickness = attributevalue(i)
                    ElseIf attributetype(i) = "layer" Then
                        layer = attributevalue(i)
                    End If
                Next i

                Select Case layer

                    Case 1
                        pencolor = Color.Red
                    Case 2

                    Case 3

                    Case 4

                    Case 5

                    Case 6

                    Case 7

                    Case 8

                    Case 9

                    Case 10

                    Case 11

                    Case 12

                    Case 13

                    Case 14

                    Case 15

                    Case 16
                        pencolor = Color.Green
                    Case 17
                        pencolor = Color.Indigo
                    Case 18
                        pencolor = Color.Yellow
                    Case 19

                    Case 20

                    Case 21

                    Case 22

                    Case 23

                    Case 24

                    Case 25

                    Case 26

                    Case 27

                    Case 28

                    Case 29

                    Case 30

                    Case 31

                    Case 32

                    Case 33

                    Case 34

                    Case 35

                    Case 36

                    Case 37

                    Case 38

                    Case 39

                    Case 40

                    Case 41

                    Case 42

                    Case 43

                    Case 44

                    Case 45

                    Case 46

                    Case 47

                    Case 48

                    Case 49

                    Case 50

                    Case 51

                    Case 52

                    Case 53

                    Case 54

                    Case 55

                    Case 56

                    Case 57

                    Case 58

                    Case 59

                    Case 60

                    Case 61

                    Case 62

                    Case 63

                    Case 64

                    Case 65

                    Case 66

                    Case 67

                    Case 68

                    Case 69

                    Case 70

                    Case 71

                    Case 72

                    Case 73

                    Case 74

                    Case 75

                    Case 76

                    Case 77

                    Case 78

                    Case 79

                    Case 80

                    Case 81

                    Case 82

                    Case 83

                    Case 84

                    Case 85

                    Case 86

                    Case 87

                    Case 88

                    Case 89

                    Case 90

                    Case 91

                    Case 92

                    Case 93

                    Case 94

                    Case 95

                    Case 96

                    Case 97

                    Case 98

                    Case 99

                End Select

                Dim Pen As New Pen(pencolor, thickness)
                Dim point1 As New Point(x1 * gscale + gmargin, y1 * gscale + gmargin)
                Dim point2 As New Point(x2 * gscale + gmargin, y2 * gscale + gmargin)
                g = WorkArea.CreateGraphics
                g.DrawLine(Pen, point1, point2)
                Pen.Dispose()
            Case "layer"


            Case Else

        End Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the xml.  Check XML as follows : From VS Project Menu : Add New Item : New XML File.  Past the XML into window.  Errors wil show up like any compiler errors in the error list.

Comment: The only error in the xml file it found was that the minversion attribute is not declared. Would that even matter?

Comment: Not sure.  Sometimes a required element/attribute in a schema will prevent an xml from loading.  It depends on the methods you are using to load the xml and the options in XmlDocuement/XDocument that are set.  I don't have all these combinations memorized.